Supporting JPA Sequence and UUID IDs at the same time
I would like to support UUID and Sequence IDs in my JPA entity class in different situations.
Case 1: For existing deployments I would like to use the sequence number
Case 2: For new deployments I would like to use the UUID values.
Can you guys please let me know whether it is possible or not?
Example: I've a Employee class.
// Existing code
@Entity
Class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String Name;
    private String Email;
}`

But for new customers I would like to use UUIDs instead of sequence IDs. But I want to maintain the existing behavior for existing deployments. Any thoughts?
I tried the following examples but I was not successful.
a) I tried to change the Id field with a superclass and derived two classes from this.
Example:
public class Id {
}

@Embeddable
public class sequenceId extends Id {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}

@Embeddable
public class UUIdId extends Id {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
}

and maintained the base class variable in the employee table. But It was not working.
@Entity
Class Employee {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    private String Name;
    private String Email;
}

`

A primary key can only have one type in a relational database. You could transform all your old IDs to UUIDs since a UUID is an 128 bit number (they won't be normal UUIDs but you could check, for example: id = 1 would be 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 and so on...
